# How do I convert a pandas series which is multidimensional to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am fairly new to python. Presently, I have a pandas series `pds`

```
pds.shape
#(1159,)
```

`pds` has an index which is not sequential and at each index there is a `(18,100)` array

```
pds[pds.index[1]].shape
#(18, 100)
```

How can I convert this to a pandas dataframe and/or a numpy array with dimensions `(1159,18,100)`?

```
pdf = pd.DataFrame(pds)
```

gives me a pandas with shape

```
pdf.shape
(1159, 1)
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data? Maybe the first few values in `pds` and your desired output? Read more on how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work: `numpy.stack([pds[pds.index[i]] for i in range(1159)], axis=0)`?

[stack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) should put all your arrays together along the axis given.

Comment: Thank you. This does work to convert it to a 1159, 18, 100 numpy array, but I lose the indexes. Is there anyway to retain that?

Comment: The indexes are implicit. The (18,100) array at the `i`th location of the 3D array has index `i`.

Answer (score 2):

You say you want to keep indexing, that means numpy is out (someone already posted a numpy solution as well).  My recommendation would be to create a series of DataFrames, as panels are deprecated.

```
new series = pd.Series()
for index, element in pds: 
    new_series.append(pd.DataFrame(element))
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: This gave me an error. *** ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Oh, you're looking for a panel though, `DataFrame`s are inherently 2-d

Comment: *** TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'numpy.ndarray'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid

Comment: See my latest edit.  I didn't realize you needed 3 dimensions, since you asked about creating a dataframe